# Asynchronous methods not running in parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to understand async/await to see if I need to make a shift in using asynchronous calls in my `ASP.NET MVC 5` application.

I have the following when populating my view model with values:

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
myViewModel.Answer1 = await myService.CalculateAnswer1Async();
myViewModel.Answer2 = await myService.CalculateAnswer2Async();
```

And the code behind the above 2 methods:

```
public async Task<int> CalculateAnswer1Async()
{
     await Task.Delay(5000);

     return 111;
}

public async Task<int> CalculateAnswer2Async()
{
     await Task.Delay(6000);

     return 222;
}
```

To my understanding the above 2 methods will execute one after the other, first `CalculateAnswer1Async()` and then `CalculateAnswer2Async()`.  So the maximum time that it should take to complete this should be around 6 seconds (the time taken for CalculateAnswer2Async() to complete)?  But when I run the page, it takes about 11 seconds to load, which is 5 seconds + 6 seconds = 11 seconds.

Could someone please help clarify this to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to assume that await starts a new thread. The opposite is the case: It waits for an existing computation to complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `await`, you are pausing the current `async` method until that operation completes. The *thread* is freed to do other work, but that *method* will not continue executing until the `await` completes. I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that describes this in more detail.

If you want to do multiple asynchronous requests concurrently, then you can delay the `await` until all the tasks have started. So this is one option:

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
var task1 = myService.CalculateAnswer1Async();
var task2 = myService.CalculateAnswer2Async();
myViewModel.Answer1 = await task1;
myViewModel.Answer2 = await task2;
```

It's slightly more efficient to use `Task.WhenAll` (and often results in clearar/cleaner code):

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
var task1 = myService.CalculateAnswer1Async();
var task2 = myService.CalculateAnswer2Async();
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
myViewModel.Answer1 = await task1;
myViewModel.Answer2 = await task2;
```

And if all the operations return the same type of value (`int`, in this case), then you can avoid the "spurious awaits" by using the result of `Task.WhenAll`:

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
var task1 = myService.CalculateAnswer1Async();
var task2 = myService.CalculateAnswer2Async();
var results = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
myViewModel.Answer1 = results[0];
myViewModel.Answer2 = results[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are starting the 2nd method `CalculateAnswer2Async` **after** the 1st method completes because you `await` the result of the 1st method.

Immediately awaiting the result of an asynchronous operation is only really useful in a UI thread since it frees the UI thread to do other work instead of blocking it. But it will not introduce concurrency.

What you want to do is start the 1st method, then the 2nd, and then call `await` on both results.

```
var result1 = myService.CalculateAnswer1Async();
var result2 = myService.CalculateAnswer2Async();
myViewModel.Answer1 = await result1;
myViewModel.Answer2 = await result2;
```

---

`async`/`await` does not introduce concurrency on its own and it's entirely possible that all the code runs synchronously. But using `async` and `await` enables you to benefit from asynchronous calls while still having code that is easy to write and that behaves mostly like you would expect from a synchronous version.

Answer (score 1):

```
myViewModel.Answer1 = await myService.CalculateAnswer1Async();
```

this will block current thread until myService.CalculateAnswer1Async() is completed.
in fact when ever you use await keyword you are telling the executing thread: "Hey wait unitl im done with this operation and then you are free to exceute next line of code".

Edit: 
while myService.CalculateAnswer1Async(); is doing its job the main thread can come back to some thing called [SynchronizationContext](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I) and when myService.CalculateAnswer1Async() is done doing its work. it will return and go for rest of method.

Comment: How would I change it to run asynchronously?

Comment: It does not really block the current thread, but the observable effect for the method you are in is very similar.

Comment: it already runs asynchronously but im afraid you dont know difference between Parallel Programming and asynchronous. the big difference with regular async programming is that when you use await it dosnt block current thread its just ordering to wait.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, await blocks execution of your method until the async method is completed, effectivly running them one by one.

What you actually want to do is run them in parallel:

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
Task<int>[] tasks = new []
{
   myService.CalculateAnswer1Async();
   myService.CalculateAnswer2Async();
};

Task.WaitAll(tasks);

myViewModel.Answer1 = tasks[0].Result;
myViewModel.Answer2 = tasks[1].Result;
```